# How do I convert .htaccess code to web.config?

Tags: .htaccess, web-config, translate

I have a PHP CMS in Apache and my `.htaccess` is below here:

```
 # -FrontPage-

IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*

# AuthType Basic
# AuthUserFile /home/tcdgroup/.htpasswd
# AuthName tadbir-group

# Require user test 


RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
```

and I want to translate it to web.config for an IIS web server.

I searched and I found "URL Rewrite" tools to translate the format and the summery is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1">
                    <match url="^\.htaccess$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden" statusDescription="Forbidden" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^.*$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^&quot;&quot;$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/public/index.php" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 3">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/public/.*$" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/public/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 4" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^.*$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="None" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 5" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^public/.*$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/public/index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But when I upload it to my server, the following error shows up:

> **500 - Internal server error**. There is a problem with the resource you
>   are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

What could be the reason for this error?

Answer (score 0):

Please, make sure that the URL rewrite module is installed and enabled it on your IIS. Otherwise, IIS can't understand the  tag in the web.config file.